# 'IConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'GetSection'

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I am trying to add authentication to a web api with .Net 5 but I get the error above in the method I am creating the token.

```
private string CreateToken(User user)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username)
        };

        // The underlined error is on the line below on the GetSection method.
        SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        SigningCredentials creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

I have done this in a previous project before and it worked fine. Added the same packages in the same version of .Net.

Not sure what else could be causing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that `IConfiguration` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`?

Comment: This little question has made me solve the issue. I didn't realise I was calling using AutoMapper.Configuration; instead of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.

Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: IConfiguration is from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions namespace so install the same it should work

Comment: All that was needed was change the library from Automapper.Configuration to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. Didn't need to install anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IConfiguration` interface should come from the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` library.

In this case the `IConfiguration` interface was a definition from `AutoMapper.Configuration`.

Perhaps the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` library also may be required because of `IOptions<>`.

Comment: That is correct. When I used the compiler to insert the library I must of added Automapper.Configuration by accident. I figured it out when someone asked me on the comments above. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration was the correct library to add and Automapper.Configuration had to be removed.